# ios 11 determine if UIButton is on a modal?

Tags: uibutton, uinavigationbar, modalviewcontroller, ios11

ios 11 has a different navigation bar structure and I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to determine if a custom UIButton implementation can determine if it is inside a modal or not.

button's superview is this new class `_UITAMICAdaptorView` and that view says its superview is nil so I'm unsure how else to approach this question.

Comment: I have the same issue, i animate some of my bar button items which were all perfect, iOS 11 and `_UITAMICAdaptorView` messed it up..!.

Comment: I am finding this an issue with UIBarButtonItems added to a UIToolBar, they no longer have a superView so we can't set their constraints when the view is loaded